# How to find item in array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have array like this :

```
array = [
    {
        id:'ABC',
        content: ''XYZ,
        people : 
        [
            'User 1',
            'User 2'
        ]
    }
    {
        id:'ABC',
        content: ''XYZ,
        people : 
        [
            'User 3',
            'User 4'
        ]
    }
]
```

I want to find obj have `people = user 3`. Here my code bellow :

```
array.forEach(function(item, index){
    var item = item.reverse().find(item => item.people.indexOf('User 3'));
    console.log(item);
});
```

Because I want get latest obj so I use `reverse()`. It's not working ? What can I do now. Thank

Comment: what is `data`? i don't see it in your code

Comment: If your want to get the latest item, why do you want to get `user 3` instead of `user 4`. By the way, I cannot see any need to use JQuery here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
array.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.people.indexOf('User 3') > -1);
        console.log(item);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can filter such objects -

```js
let array = [{
  id: 'ABC',
  content: '',
  people: [
    'User 1',
    'User 2'
  ]
}, {
  id: 'ABC',
  content: '',
  people: [
    'User 3',
    'User 4'
  ]
}];

console.log(array.filter(obj => -1 != obj.people.indexOf("User 3")));
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using the `item` or `index` argument to the `forEach` function (you name some other things `item`, but you never use the arguments), so your function is going to do the same thing every iteration.

```
var result = array.find( function ( item ) {
    return item.people.includes( 'User 3' );
})
```

`result` will be 1 object. If you're looking for all objects with `User 3`, use `filter` instead of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you most recent result.

```js
const arr = [
    {
        id:'ABC',
        content: 'XYZ',
        people : 
        [
            'User 1',
            'User 2'
        ]
    },
    {
        id:'ABC',
        'content': 'XYZ',
        'people' : 
        [
            'User 3',
            'User 4'
        ]
    }
]

console.log(arr.filter(item => item.people.includes('User 3')).slice(-1)[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `filter()` to get all result of the search. Use `pop()` to get the last one.

```js
let array = [
    {"id":"ABC","content":"XYZ","people":["User 1","User 2"]},
    {"id":"ABC","content":"XYZ","people":["User 3","User 4"]},
    {"id":"XXX","content":"XXX","people":["User 3","User 4"]}
];

let toSearch = 'User 3';
let result = array.filter(o => o.people.includes(toSearch)).pop();

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Array.find()` method like:

```js
var array = [
    {
        id:'ABC',
        content: 'XYZ',
        people : 
        [
            'User 1',
            'User 2'
        ]
    },
    {
        id:'ABC',
        content: 'XYZ',
        people : 
        [
            'User 3',
            'User 4'
        ]
    }
];

var res = array.find(obj => obj.people.indexOf('User 3') !== -1);
console.log(res);
```